# Identify and count points inside a user defined segment

Tags: python, matplotlib, count

I'm trying to identify and count data points that are within a user defined "wedge" selection. The data points each have their own ID number and are being loaded from a CSV catalog file, while the the "wedge" is simply a series of lines drawn over the plot.

Below is an example of the plot:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

x = ID['x']
y = ID['y']

plt.figure()
plt.scatter(x, y)
plt.plot([-1, -1, 2, 2, ], [4, 1, -2, 4], color='r', linewidth=1, linestyle='--')
plt.xlim(-4,4)
plt.ylim(-4,4)
plt.show()
```

Sample plot: http://i.imgur.com/UENwbks.png

I'm looking for two outputs

1) A list of all IDs (data points) that are within the "wedge"

2) A count of all IDs (data points), which is a pretty simple task once the above has been achieved!

My initial thought was something along the lines of:

```
ID['x'] >= -1 and ID['x'] <= 2 and ???
```

where ??? is the area above the wedge (perhaps a linear equation?).

Any assistance is appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could define a Path and use its [contains_points](http://matplotlib.org/api/path_api.html#matplotlib.path.Path.contains_points) method:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.path as mpath

x, y = np.random.random((2, 100))*8 - 4
points = np.column_stack([x, y])
verts = np.array([[-1, -1, 2, 2, ], [4, 1, -2, 4]]).T
path = mpath.Path(verts)
points_inside = points[path.contains_points(points)]

plt.figure()
plt.scatter(x, y)
plt.plot([-1, -1, 2, 2, ], [4, 1, -2, 4], color='r', linewidth=1, linestyle='--')
plt.scatter(points_inside[:,0], points_inside[:,1], c='r', s=50)
plt.xlim(-4,4)
plt.ylim(-4,4)
plt.show()
```

[image]